# rake db:create with mysql on OS X 10.7 Lion fails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rubygems

I'm trying to install rvm, mysql and rails on a fresh OS X 10.7 installation. They all install correctly individually, but I can't seem to get them to work together.

When I try the command `rake db:create`, I get the following error:

```
db/test.sqlite3 already exists
db/test.sqlite3 already exists
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Mysql::Error

Tasks: TOP => db:create
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

- Mac OS X 10.7.0
- rvm 1.6.32
- Ruby 1.9.2
- MySQL 5.1.5.15
- Rails 3.0.9

I installed the mysql gem using the correct instructions. I added this to ~/.bash_profile:

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/mysql/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"
```

I did this command:

```
env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" sudo gem install mysql -v='2.8.1' -- --with-mysql-dir=/usr/local/mysql --with-mysql-lib=/usr/local/mysql/lib --with-mysql-include=/usr/local/mysql/include --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
```

When I do `gem list`, I can see that version 2.8.1 of the mysql gem is installed. I've kinda run out of ideas now, any suggestions? Thanks.

database.yml:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: terra_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: root
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

Comment: In your first code block it seems to be thinking in sqlite.  Could you post the development section of your database.yml-password and Gemfile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for the input, I managed to fix the problem. The problem was that rails couldn't connect with the server using the provided credentials. Because for some reason, there weren't any MySQL users, not even a `root` user. I ran this command:

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin -u root password "root"
```

Which created a root user, let me connect to the server and fixed the problem!

Comment: This solved the problem for me after installing mysql with the recommended `brew install mysql` on OSX.

Answer (score 0):

The sqlite error is while creating the test database. You show the development section of your database.yml, so either your test section of database.yml specifies sqlite or you don't have a test database specified.

Comment: The sqlite error is not the problem. It's about the mysql one.

Comment: The problem you're experiencing is directly related to the sqlite error. Rake is aborting because your test database is already there. Delete the `db/sqlite3` or fix your the test section of your database.yml. If it still doesn't work, edit your post with the error you get at that point.